# Setting Drupal root directory to 777

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-6

A company mine is working with is having permissions issues for uploading files (via FTP). We found a workaround of putting everything to 777 (not my first choice, but ease of use trumps security here).

The problem with this is that Drupal breaks upon putting the root directory as 777.

Why is this? How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Typically your files directory should be:

```
chmod -R 775 files
```

But also make sure your owner and group are correct. The owner in this case should be your ftp user. And your group should be the apache user.

```
chgrp -R apache_user files
chown -R ftp_user files
```

Comment: Yes, when 775 is the directory permissions, uploads do not work (in Drupal, in FTP they do)

Comment: Yes but is your group set to the apache user. That was the more important point here. You need both or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Having problem to upload files with ftp or with drupal? Drupal need write permission in sites/default/files to save images and css etc.

Maybe its problem with owner too? 
Check this page: http://drupal.org/node/244924

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this is that Drupal breaks upon putting the root
>   directory as 777.

Actually you need to change not root of Drupal directory but the directory `sites/default/files`.

If you want to do that in **easiest way** change this directory permissions to 777:

```
cd <your Drupal root>/sites/default
chmod -R 777 files
```

The **secure way** is to set your WWW user (e.g. `www-data`) as an owner of this directory:

```
cd <your Drupal root>/sites/default
chown -R www-data files
chmod -R 775 files
```

Also you can add your group (e.g. `my_group`):

```
chgrp -R my_group files
```